# Angular 2 disable/enable reactive form element on load

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic reactive form component. You pass it a set of fields and it builds a form.

My issue comes when I have a checkbox element that controls whether another element within the same form is enabled or disabled. I have no issue with updating the sibling element when the control checkbox is changed but when the view is loaded I get the good old `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error (only in dev obviously)

```
public ngOnInit() {
    // If the element is a field controller subscribe to it's value changes
    if (this.elementVal.isFieldController === true) {
        // This is what's causing the issue
        this.toggleControlledFields(this.form.get(this.elementVal.key).value);
        this.form.get(this.elementVal.key).valueChanges
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data, 'the data');
                this.toggleControlledFields(data);
            });
    }
}
```

A `fieldController` may control one or more values so I loop through each one and disable or enable the field it controls:-

```
public toggleControlledFields(value) {
    if (value === '' || value === false) {
        this.elementVal.fieldsToControl.forEach((field) => {
            this.form.get(field).disable();
        });
    } else {
        this.elementVal.fieldsToControl.forEach((field) => {
            this.form.get(field).enable();
        });
    }
}
```

Because I do this `onInit` I get said error, I've tried adding in a `detectChanges()` and I've tried different lifecycle hooks but for the life of me can't solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I added the below life cycle hook with a detect changes and that seems to have fixed my issue, maybe this will help someone else..

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Saves my day - especially when the update of the DOM-elemnts is dependent on internal validation mechanism!!! THX

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: I'm disabling a field in the ctor (i.e. it's never, ever enabled - just there to show the field; I do it before the data is even loaded), and I seem to have to do what you said to avoid the error even though it's not an issue of dynamically changing enable/disable after the data or form has loaded.  This is crazy.  I must be doing something wrong, right??  This can't be by-design...